# Uncaught reference error, $ is not defined. How to fix it?

Tags: jquery

jQuery
What is wrong with the first jQuery line, it says that the $ is not defined.
Does someone know what im doing wrong?

```
  $("#selectsmrtfldr").change(function () {
          var selected_option = $('#selectsmrtfldr').val();
          if (selected_option === '1') {
              $('#fnivel2').attr('pk','1').hide();
          }
          if (selected_option != '1') {
              $("#fnivel2").removeAttr('pk').show();
          }
      })
```

This is my HTML Code

```
<div class="documentsearchform">
    <form action="./" method="post">
        <div class="smartfolder">
            <h1>Documents</h1>
            <label id="smartfoldertitel">SmartFolder:</label>
            <select id="selectsmrtfldr"name='smartfolder'>
                <option value="1"></option>
                <?php
                echo "Kies gebruiker om te verwijderen";
                echo "<br />";
                include('./database.php');
                echo "<br />";
                $query1="select * from gebruikers";
                $uitvoer1=mysqli_query($connectie,$query1);
                echo "<form action='./gebruikersverwijderen2.php' method='POST'>";
                while($nextrecord=mysqli_fetch_array($uitvoer1))
                {
                    echo "<option value='" .$nextrecord[0]. "'>" .$nextrecord[1]. " " .$nextrecord[2]. "</option>";
                }
                ?>

            </select>
            <input id="fnivel2" hidden="hidden" />
```

Comment: do you have jquery included?

Comment: No, the jQuery is in an extended file jquery.js

Comment: yes, that's jQuery is.what I asked is did you included jquery for your html. like 
`<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` if so, try replacing all **$** with **jQuery** and check if it gives any errors

Comment: Yes, like this: <script type="text/javascript"
        src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: why two jquery includes?

Comment: Im pretty new to jQuery, dont know actualy.

Comment: comment out both lines and use as this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`. After that include your js file as this `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>`

Comment: Have done that, i get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: to which js file? I checked jquery link works fine. Also can you show me the whole error you see?screenshot would be helpful

Comment: No nevermind, it gives no error, but it just doesnt work.
I want to display the hidden input field when i click on a option in the selectbox.
But that does not work.

Comment: try ``alert(selected_option) after `var selected_option = $('#selectsmrtfldr').val();`and see if you get the correct value

Comment: when i add that, i get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: In the jquery.js

Comment: please show me a screenshot of the error. Also try to put your jquery code inside document ready **jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("#selectsmrtfldr").change(function () {
          var selected_option = $('#selectsmrtfldr').val();
          if (selected_option === '1') {
              $('#fnivel2').attr('pk','1').hide();
          }
          if (selected_option != '1') {
              $("#fnivel2").removeAttr('pk').show();
          }
      });

});**

Comment: Sorry, but how can i add a screenshot?

Comment: take a screenshot and upload to imgur

Comment: https://gyazo.com/fc26836401c2a34c7b78ca7f676eefc5

Comment: do you have multiple jquery files included?

Comment: No, i have just one file

Comment: The document ready fixed it, thanks for helping!

Comment: anytime :) . glad to hear it

Answer (score 3):

That error can only be caused by one of three things:

- Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
  You have a botched version of jQuery.
- This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may 
  have overwritten the $ variable.
- You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as 
  such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

Comment: I've checked all those things, but none of them is the solution, i stil get the error.